# RST RAID-0 NTFS partitions not available to mount

Tags: partitioning, raid, ntfs, compatibility

- I've a double boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu mate on separate disks (F8 boot select).
- I've a RAID-0 block made in Windows 10 on RST that is working fine as secondary disk. This block is not meant to boot, just to store and share data between both systems.

I can't see the partitions of this raid block on Ubuntu Mate, although gdisk doesn't list the partitions, gnome-disk-utility see the GPT, but no partitions to mount.

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/dm-0
[sudo] Mot de passe de wingarmac : 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/dm-0: 3907039744 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F554FF29-FF7D-4A79-8D05-3ADF30EF3BED
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907039710
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2527 sectors (1.2 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34           32767   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   2           32768      3907035135   1.8 TiB     0700  Basic data partition
   3      3907035136      3907037183   1024.0 KiB  8300
```

I open Gparted with the start menu, I can see my RAID-0 shown as: /dev/mapper/isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1
I couldn't do any modification at all in Gparted this way.

I could see my RAID block was called: /dev/dm-0 in the gnome-disk-utility

I tried to open Gparted with the terminal and the command:

```
$ sudo gparted /dev/dm-0
```

I made a try, by changing the flag on the "Basic data partition" to `irst`, then back to `msftres`. this made the partition map to /dev/mapper/isw_module_Volume1p1. I could even browse the folders and create content on the partition ones mounted.
The problem remains after reboot. It seems to reset the operation done. Even after I tried to change the mount options in gnome-disks.

I found that /etc/mtab is where the current disk mapping (like USB drives and other hotplugged) are stored. I tried by adding the line concerning the right partition mount to fstab, but the partition doesn't mount after restart:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1p2 /media/wingarmac/Data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

**Resuming the problem:**

**Clue 1:** Why do I have two mappings for my raid block?:

- /dev/mapper/isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1
- /dev/dm-0

The answer for this seems to be that /dev/mapper/isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1 is the raid volume device detected at boot, and /dev/dm-0 is the mapping of this drive for the drive system mounts.

**Clue 2:** Why do I need to change the flag to be able to mount the ntfs partition?

When I do this, it's like a new check for partitions occurs, and enables the drive mapping of those partitions.

**Clue 3:** Why can't I automount this partition after reboot?

I've found that Windows uses GPT to initialise disks larger as 2Tb. It is also advised to disk that should contain more as 4 partitions.
The point is that Ubuntu doesn't look after MBR partitions on a GPT disk at boot it seems. My dm-0 (GPT disk) is listed, but no dm-1 mapped (contained MBR partition).

When I use gparted /dev/dm-0 I'm able to see the MBR NTFS partition contained, and another reserved one. By changing the flag on the partition to any other and back, makes the partition map into /dev/dm-1. Then gparted is able to verify it, because it's mapped.
During the verification, gparted request a resize, that results in "resize not needed". But this makes the partition able to be mounted by Ubuntu. Although it's like everything's reset after a reboot, even if I enter the mount details in fstab.

The point is the encapsulated MBR isn't mapped to dm-1 at boot.
It seems not even been detected because dm-1 is mapped, the volume /dev/mapper/isw_module_Volume1p1 isn't discovered yet. Only the block (/dev/mapper/isw_module_Volume1) and raid members are listed in gdisk after boot.

When I enter the command:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/dm-0
```

I get these results:

/dev/dm-0 DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR Windows 7 english at offset 0x163 "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x17b "Error loading operating system" at offset 0x19a "Missing operating system", disk signature 0x87d4000f; partition 1 : ID=0x27, start-CHS (0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2048, 3907033088 sectors

The partition was made on Windows, but the Windows is installed on another drive.
It's like the drive is not mapped on boot, because it's not able to find the system on it.
I do not need this partition to be a boot entry, just that it is automatically mounted in Ubuntu. Can I disable this check for operating system on this disk/partition ?

I wonder if I can repeat the operations made by gparted at boot when detecting this disk/partition.
Here is a sample of the Gparted GUI operation to be able to mount it:
[gparted_details](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR111BH4zKs9okMWAsS5dEptyRxhNygIpBnVkLcwKugYb9EtS59mn3BkohaXa_8sikCk7CH2mMoVJ2r/pub)

I found an important information about the UUID of the block device by using the command:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/dm-0
```

This gave me as result for UUID on this drive:
ATTR{dm/uuid}=="DMRAID-isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1"

Now I only get the following error concerning my raid-0, with the command `sudo journalctl -p 3`

```
kernel: ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'
```

But no fstab error on mount point anymore and still no partition mapped.

[Here you'll find all identification commands used and their respective results.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRJu2rAUjgAmgUYLvdOTEteOYPlMtXrBTQSab6POxjcvjgsQA9R_Wx-gmch_RrBN2aBwsE1oadB_wJj/pub)

I've found a better way to map the partition after reboot, instead of using gparted. Now I just have to enter the command: `sudo dmraid  -ay  -f  isw` with as results:

```
RAID set "isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1" already active
RAID set "isw_cfjifbibag_Volume1p1" was activated
```

Now I can mount the partition in gnome-disk like others. The only problem left, is that updating GRUB on this device has no point since it's for storage. So I have no clue on how to make the boot process do the check `dmraid  -ay  -f  isw` instead of only `dmraid  -ay` like it seems to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of [this page on Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto), containing a little error in this part:

What about the pre-boot environment?
The default package dmraid comes with scripts that are insufficient to actually activate the partitions on the array.
You must copy the script to /etc and append it:

```
cp /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/dmraid /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top
echo "dmraid -ay" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top
```

This last command gave me as results:

```
bash: /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top: is a folder
```

So I opened the folder **/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top** and saw a file dmraid inside it. I presume it was meant to add this command into this file.

So I did it manually by editing the file myself.
Command needed to make dmraid look for partition with Intel metadata:

```
dmraid -ay -f isw
```

This command should be considered at boot time. Therefor we need to add this command to a script in the folder **/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top** in the file named **dmraid** like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmraid -ay -f isw
# local-top script for dmraid.

PREREQS=""
prereqs()
{
    echo $PREREQS
}

case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

. /scripts/functions
wait_for_udev 30

# Activate any dmraid arrays that were not identified by udev and vol_id.

if devices=$(dmraid -r -c); then
    for dev in $devices; do
        dmraid-activate $dev
    done
fi
```

***Special note:***

*For a clean install do not forget to reinstall dmraid after editing*

***/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/dmraid***

*by using the command as root:*

`apt install --reinstall dmraid libdmraid1.0.0.rc16`

*Like mentioned on the [Ubuntu Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto)*

Now my dmraid NTFS partition on Intel RST is mounting automatically even after reboot.
I just had to make this line active again in **/etc/fstab** :

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/F69A259A9A2557FF /mnt/data auto rw,nosuid,nofail,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for going into #ubuntu-doc and attempting to help contribute to the wiki by addressing the issue you encountered.

Comment: @guiverc You're welcome. I'm glad i could help !

Comment: See option -a explaination on: https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmraid